# React-native: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

would love to use your help. 
I'm messing around with stack-navigator in react-native but I've been stuck now for a while on the error mentioned in the title. I made the code the most basic I can but still cant figure out the bug. I guess it's something about the accessibility of this.props but I dont understand it yet..

Heres the code:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Animated,DeviceEventEmitter,Text,View,StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity,TextInput,Button,Image,Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from '/Users/amitnelinger/Desktop/MobileProjects/newProj/node_modules/react-navigation'




const App = (props) => {
    return(
     const { navigate } = props.navigation;
     <View>
                <Button 
                    onPress={() => navigate('song')} 
                    title = "MotherFucker Jones"
                />  

      </View>
    );
 }

App.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home screen',
};

export default App
```

index.ios.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Animated,DeviceEventEmitter,Text,View,StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity,TextInput,Button,Image,Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import App from '/Users/amitnelinger/Desktop/MobileProjects/newProj/app/components/App.js'
import song from '/Users/amitnelinger/Desktop/MobileProjects/newProj/app/components/song.js'
import {StackNavigator} from '/Users/amitnelinger/Desktop/MobileProjects/newProj/node_modules/react-navigation'

export default class newProj extends Component{

    render(){
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        return(
            <App navigation = { navigation } />
        );
    }
}

const simpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: App},
    song: {screen: song}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('newProj',() => newProj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the StackNavigator, you're just passing a navigation prop that's undefined. Swap out App with your StackNavigator and it should fix your problem:

```
export default class newProj extends Component{

    render(){    
        return(
            <simpleApp />
        );
    }
}

const simpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: App},
    song: {screen: song}
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Very much, indeed it works. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you aren't calling the navigation properly. The full prop to change navigation is 'this.props.navigation.navigate('song'). Give that adjustment a try

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I've tried it already and it didn't work